# Is this the correct definition for a splitting field extension for a set?

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

Let *K* be a field and *S* be a nonempty subset of *K*[*x*]. A splitting field extension for *S* is a field extension *L*:*K* with the properties

(i) each element of *S* splits in *L* and

(ii) each element of *S* does not split in a proper subfield of *L* which includes *K*.

Thank you

Comment: There's no reason to require that $S$ be nonempty.

Comment: The text I am working from has (ii) if J is a subfield of L which includes K and each element of S splits in J, then J = L. I would like to know if the (ii) posted is the same as the (ii) in this comment. Thanks

Comment: I have much better luck with the part of the proof I was stuck on when I use (ii) for each proper subfield J of L which includes K, there exists at least one element of S which does not split in J. This is more usable for me than the (ii) given in the text.

Comment: FWIW, the proof I was stuck on is part of the overall proof of the fact: A field extension L:K is normal if and only if L:K is the splitting field extension for at least one nonempty subset of K[x].